# using htaccess to restrict access on root when subdomains are also present

Tags: .htaccess, shared-hosting

Consider the following structure:

`example.com` locates to `public_html/index.php`

`example2.com` locates to `public_html/SUB/e2/index.php`

I want to take `example.com` down for maintenance, and thought htaccess would be the best method. But then I became worried that doing so would block access to the second (unrelated) site, because to the server it is located *within* the first site.

Would an htaccess-driven block at `example.com` also kill off `example2.com` ?

Comment: Generally, yes. What kind of block are you thinking of?

Comment: Hey buddy. If possible, I want to take down my main site for several weeks while I overhaul the framework and reload all the content yet still keep the other independent domain physically located in a subfolder online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isnt there a thing like "priority" in htaccess files?

I mean e.g. you first block the access to "public_html"

and then allow access to "public_html/SUB/e2" etc. ?

Must work i think.